# how to show all orders amount respective to every user in a table without duplicating a username twice

Tags: django, django-queryset

[image]i have this order model:

```
class Order(models.Model):
productType = [
    ('Document', 'Document'),
    ('Parcel', 'Parcel'),
    ('Box', 'Box')
]
serviceType = [
    ('Home', 'Home delivery'),
    ('Office', 'Office delivery'),
    ('Pick up from office', 'Pick up from office'),
]
delivery_StatusType = [
    ('Return', 'Return'),
    ('Delivering', 'Delivering'),
    ('Pending', 'Pending'),
    ('Complete', 'Complete')
]
statustype = [
    ('Paid', 'Paid'),
    ('Cash on delivery', 'Cash on delivery')
]

status = [
    ('Instant', 'Instant'),
    ('Same Day', 'Same Day'),
    ('Others', 'Others')
]
payment_types = [
    ('Cash', 'Cash'),
    ('Wallet', 'Wallet'),
    ('Online', 'Online')
]
CHOICE_AREA = [
    ('Inside Dhaka', 'Inside Dhaka'),
    ('Dhaka Suburb', 'Dhaka Suburb'),
    ('Outside Dhaka', 'Outside Dhaka')
]

user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

receiver = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, unique=False)
receiver_Contact = models.CharField(
    max_length=20, blank=False, unique=False)
receiver_Email = models.CharField(
    max_length=100, blank=False, unique=False)

payment = models.CharField(
    max_length=100, choices=payment_types, blank=False)

area = models.CharField(
    max_length=100, choices=CHOICE_AREA, blank=True, null=True)
weight = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
service = models.CharField(choices=serviceType,  max_length=100)
product_Type = models.CharField(choices=productType, max_length=100)
contents = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, unique=False)
quantity = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, unique=False)

package = models.ForeignKey(
    Package, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=0)
priority = models.CharField(
    choices=status, blank=True, null=True, max_length=20)
amount = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, unique=False)
delivery_Status = models.CharField(
    choices=delivery_StatusType, blank=True, null=True, max_length=50)

paid = models.BooleanField(default=False)
reference_id = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, unique=True)
delivery_time = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
created = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
tran_id = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
driver = models.ForeignKey(
    User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='driver', blank=True, null=True)
driver_amount = models.CharField(max_length=5, blank=False, default='0')

delivery_now = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
delivery_later = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)

accept = models.BooleanField(default=False)

start = models.BooleanField(blank=True, null=True)
finish = models.BooleanField(blank=True, null=True)

pick_up_latitude = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=50)
pick_up_longitude = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=50)

delivery_latitude = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=50)
delivery_longitude = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=50)

otp = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)

pickup_finish = models.BooleanField(default=False)
approve_change_delivery_address = models.BooleanField(
    blank=True, null=True, default=False)

confirm_change_delivery_address = models.BooleanField(
    blank=True, null=True, default=False)


def __str__(self):
    return self.user.username
```

user model:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
CITIES = [
    ('Dhaka','Dhaka'),
    ('Rajshahi','Rajshahi'),
    ('Chittagong','Chittagong'),
    ('Sylhet','Sylhet'),
    ('Khulna','Khulna'),
    ('Mymensingh','Mymensingh'),
    ('Rangpur','Rangpur'),
    ('Dinajpur','Dinajpur'),
]

Vehicle_type = [
    ('Truck','Truck'),
    ('Van','Van'),
    ('Bike','Bike')
]
email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
contact = models.CharField(null=False,blank=False,max_length=20)
contact2 = models.CharField(null=True,blank=True,max_length=20)
contact3 = models.CharField(null=True,blank=True,max_length=20)
contact4 = models.CharField(null=True,blank=True,max_length=20)
address = models.CharField(null=False,blank=False,max_length=100)
address2 = models.CharField(null=True,blank=True,max_length=100)
postal_code = models.CharField(null=True,blank=True,max_length=10)
city = models.CharField(max_length=30,choices=CITIES)
username = models.CharField(max_length=200,unique=True)
user_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/images/')
n_id = models.CharField(max_length=100)
quote = models.CharField(max_length=250,blank=True,null=True,default='Bio Here. . .')

driving_license = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/documents/')
vehicle_type = models.CharField(max_length=30,choices=Vehicle_type)
vehicle_no = models.CharField(max_length=50)

latitude = models.CharField(max_length=100,default=0)
longitude = models.CharField(max_length=100,default=0)

is_driver = models.BooleanField(default=False)
is_delivery_man = models.BooleanField(default=False)
is_merchant = models.BooleanField(default=False)
is_agent = models.BooleanField(default=False)
is_user = models.BooleanField(default=False)
is_available = models.BooleanField(default=False)

def __str__(self):
    return self.username
```

now the problem is i want to show the username , total amount collections and total orders by individual users(is_agent).no name will be repeated twice though the queryset can have multiple orders agains a user.
i just want to show a users orders total amount and total deliveries in a table row,then other row will be for other users. N.B.filtering (delivery_status="Complete")

update:

```
agents = User.objects.filter(is_active=True,is_agent=True)
    for agent in agents:
        agent_id = agent.id
        all_orders = Order.objects.filter(user_id = agent_id, delivery_Status="Pending", delivery_time__month = date,
        delivery_time__year = year)
```

now in here i want every agents total delivery count and total amount collected from them but not like showing same user's all querysets but instead i want only by his name will appear once in the table and all deliveries total amount and total deliveries into that row just like the given table

itried this but this has no track of which collection is for whom

```
individual_orders = []
    final_list = []
    grand_final_list = []
    order_amount = []
    individual_orders_count = []
    agents = User.objects.filter(is_active=True,is_agent=True)
    for agent in agents:
        agent_id = agent.id
        all_orders = Order.objects.filter(user_id = agent_id, delivery_Status="Pending", delivery_time__month = date,
        delivery_time__year = year)

        if all_orders:
            individual_orders.append(all_orders)
            individual_orders_count.append(len(all_orders))

        cash_collection = Order.objects.filter(user_id = agent_id, delivery_Status="Pending", delivery_time__month = date,
        delivery_time__year = year).values('amount').aggregate(Sum('amount'))

        for k,v in cash_collection.items():
            if v:
                order_amount.append(v)

    for query in individual_orders:
        for entry in query:
            final_list.append(entry.user.username)
    grand_final_list = list(dict.fromkeys(final_list))
```

this table

Comment: Can you please show us the queryset which you tried to filtering

Comment: @satyajit brother please see the updates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i found a way i am showing the demo here

```
def driver_deliveries(request):
    name = {}
    data = []
    count = Order.objects.filter(driver__is_driver=True).distinct()
    for i in count:
        query = Order.objects.filter(driver_id=i.driver.id,delivery_Status="Complete").count()
        name[i.driver.username] = data
        data.append(query)
        data = []
    print(name)
    for k,v in name.items():
        print(k)
        for i in v:
            print(i)
    return render(request,'user/driver_deliveries.html',{'name': name})
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe this helps you?

```
all_orders = Order.objects.filter(user_id = agent_id, delivery_Status="Pending", delivery_time__month = date,
        delivery_time__year = year).values(id, username=F(user__username)).annotate(total_amount = Sum('amount')).annotate(total_deliveries = Count('id))
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'Sum' object has no attribute 'annotate'
it shows this error

Comment: name 'user__username' is not defined also this error//// may be this will not work

Comment: I corrected my answer ... sorry I cant check the syntax for the moment - just wanted to give you the idea of using values(...) with annotate(...)

Comment: I just saw that you are using a CustomUser model ... I cant tell you if that is the reason why username is not found as field in your ForeignKey user. I have never created a custom user.